# The sleep function of C/C++ will start when the program starts running

Tags: c++

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
    sleep(3);
    std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
}
```

When outputting it will stop for three seconds on startup, not after outputting hello

Answer (score 3):

Change the first line of your function to this:

```
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
```

The `std::endl` doesn't just mean "end of line", it also means to flush the output, meaning it will actually get written instead of just sitting in a buffer.

Comment: For simple questions like this, it is more helpful if you take a few moments to search for duplicates before posting an answer. Avoiding answering the same question over and over not only saves your time, but it makes the site a better, more comprehensive resource for future viewers.